# best coding practice - draw line and circle in same function - struct, switch, class function

Tags: ios, swift

i'm learning and coding swift for a couple of month now and of course i'm still asking myself what the best practice for certain solutions is:

The Problem:
I need to print a thin Line of random Height on an image of 200x200px.
The same function should also print a circle of a fixed size onto that image.

Building that function is not the big deal, i'm rather asking myself if my solution is the best way of doing it. Basically i have util class with a class function.

Inside the class function is a switch statement based on an enum wether to print the line or the circle.
i'm thinking of to break the switch up into 2 different functions following more the facade pattern. what do you think?

here is the code and here is the [playground](https://github.com/ppoh71/playgounds/tree/master/BestPractice.playground)

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

/*
 draw a line or a circle on an image canvas
 */


/* different printing function types */
enum FuncTypes: String {
    case Line
    case Circle
    case PrintBaseHeight
    case Default
}



final class ImageUtils{

    class func drawLineOnImage(funcType: FuncTypes) -> UIImage{

        //def vars
        let drawHeight = 200
        let drawWidth  = 200
        var rectangle =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: drawWidth, height: drawHeight), false, 0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        //flipp-coords
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, CGFloat(drawHeight));
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

        //get height and color for line
        let LineHeight = Int(arc4random_uniform(200) )
        let LineColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
        var heightPercent = 0

        //context stuff
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1)

        //switch line/circle printing
        switch funcType {

        case .Circle:
            print("printing circle")
            CGContextAddArc(context, 2.5, CGFloat(drawHeight/2), 2.5, 0, CGFloat(M_PI * 2), 0)
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,LineColor.CGColor)
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,LineColor.CGColor)
            CGContextDrawPath(context, .FillStroke)

        case .Line:
            print("printing line")
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context,0, 0)
            heightPercent = LineHeight*55/100
            CGContextSetAlpha(context,0.4);
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
            rectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: drawHeight/2, width: 4, height: Int(heightPercent))
            CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle)
            CGContextStrokePath(context)
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,LineColor.CGColor)
            CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle)

        default:
            break
        }


        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return img
    }

}


let lineOnImage = ImageUtils.drawLineOnImage(FuncTypes.Line)
let circleOnImahe = ImageUtils.drawLineOnImage(FuncTypes.Circle)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example seem good. Just writing too many lines in each case don't seems to be good practise. Instead of that you can make function and use them. So if you want you can reuse same code other place in project. as well.

Facade pattern says that what logic your class do in itself should not be aware to other classes in project. So as per my suggestion your code should be like code below:

```
    //: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"


/*
 draw a line or a circle on an image canvas
 */


/* different printing function types */
enum FuncTypes: String {
    case Line
    case Circle
    case PrintBaseHeight
    case Default
}



final class ImageUtils{


    class func drawLineOnImage(funcType: FuncTypes) -> UIImage{

        //def vars
        let drawHeight = 200
        let drawWidth  = 200
//        var rectangle =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: drawWidth, height: drawHeight), false, 0)
        var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        //flipp-coords
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, CGFloat(drawHeight));
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

        //get height and color for line
//        let LineHeight = Int(arc4random_uniform(200) )
        let LineColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
//        var heightPercent = 0

        //context stuff
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1)



        //switch some func cases for image height
        switch funcType {

        case .Line:
            print("Recording")
            drawLine(&context!, height: drawHeight, LineColor: LineColor)

        case .Circle:
            print("image printingmarker")
            drawCircle(&context!, height: drawHeight, LineColor: LineColor)

        default:
            break
        }


        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return img
    }

    static func drawLine (inout context:CGContext, height:Int, LineColor : UIColor) {

        CGContextAddArc(context, 2.5, CGFloat(height/2), 2.5, 0, CGFloat(M_PI * 2), 0)
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,LineColor.CGColor)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,LineColor.CGColor)
        CGContextDrawPath(context, .FillStroke)

    }
    static func drawCircle (inout context:CGContext, height:Int, LineColor : UIColor) {

        let LineHeight = Int(arc4random_uniform(200) )
        var heightPercent = 0

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context,0, 0)
        heightPercent = LineHeight*55/100
        CGContextSetAlpha(context,0.4);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
        let rectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: height/2, width: 4, height: Int(heightPercent))
        CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,LineColor.CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle)

    }

}


let lineOnImage = ImageUtils.drawLineOnImage(FuncTypes.Line)
let circleOnImahe = ImageUtils.drawLineOnImage(FuncTypes.Circle)
```

Answer (score 0):

That function violate SOLID principle, because it does few drawings. Your thoughts are in right direction. Best solution to have few functions and has one facade on top of them